# How keep close mobile navigation menu closed upon pageloading?

Tags: css, responsive-design, joomla2.5

I have a responsive website based on Joomla 2.5 and a Joomla51 template with a mobile navigation menu being used in tablets and mobile phones.

When opening the webpage, the mobile menu stays OPEN for quite a long time, until page-rendering process is finished. Instead, I want the mobile menu to be closed during page-rendering:

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.golfanatics.de/&w=320&h=480&a=33&s=1

What can I possibly do?

Comment: _“Instead, I want the mobile menu to be closed during page-rendering”_ – well then either make it display as “closed” via CSS in the first place (not good, users without JS enabled would most likely not be able to use it then), or make the code that “closes” it run earlier than only when the whole page has finished loading …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I look at this at the moment, you have a Google font file in the head of your template (see below) and this is giving me a 400 error.

I would fix this first because it may be delaying your css files from kicking in and collapsing the mobile menu

Good luck!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial"/>
```

**Edit**

That's great that you were able to fix the font-file 400 error.

The suggestion to try and collapse the menu bar earlier might help, though you have a moderately complex CSS and JS setup, and it's difficult for me to see how to do this in practice.

I can also see some other issues that I would address first.

Tools like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or my favourite [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org) are brilliant at helping pinpoint where problems might be. If I look at your site on [WebPageTest](http://bit.ly/1kGvzZu) one thing that stands out for me is that the home page has a weight of almost 5MB, which is getting up there.

The more you can reduce this, the faster the page will load for everyone, plus it will help the menu issue.

First thing I would fix is the size of some of the images. I can see there are a number of large images loading for some reason, e.g. http://www.golfhouse.de/img/produktbilder/xxl/52418099-01-GHIE.jpg

Maybe you can downsize these.

Next you want to try and both minimise, and compress the css, js and image files. Ideally you could also combine all the CSS files into a single file, and likewise for the JS scripts. Options like [JCH Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/12088) make this easy.

You could also look into using a CDN like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com), which will both speed up your site and reduce the load on your server.

I would expect that the combined effect of the above would help your home page load atleast twice as fast, probably more.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dear David, thank you, that was an important hint. I rectified this, and the menu seems to close slightly quicker. The above comment made by @CBroe is exactly what I want to do: to make the CLOSING CODE run earlier... But where to search for that?

Comment: Dear David, thank you very much again. I got in touch with the menu programmers and they will shortly provide me with some file updates, which hopefully rectify the problem. Thanks also for all other remarks and hints. I am already using Amazon Cloudfront, and also CSS combining and various other optimization filters via Google mod_pagespeed. However, I was not aware of the large images hosted by www.golfhouse.de and deleted them out of the module, so pagesize as well as load time has improved significantly. Very best regards, Ralph

Comment: Good going Ralph, it looks to me as if the home page weight is only 35% of what it was. Unrelated to your initial mobile nav question, if you look at the page waterfall below, the bottle neck is now the 1.588 sec to download the home page HTML. In part this will be influenced by the sites erver, and you may not have any say in this. If you haven't already, you could also try enabling the cache in both Global configuration > System  and Plugin Manager > System Cache and see if you can reduce this 1.588 time. http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140323_AQ_3d5487eae6124a649f05be3e1c30772c/1/details/